# How to split string from number of / in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My sting is like this

```
console.log(fields.urlOfFolder); // console is [ '122/122/47/49/50' ] 
and i want only first 122 how it is possible ?
```

i tried this code..

```
var customerid = fields.urlOfFolder.split('/')[0];
console.log(customerid);
```

but it gives error like this `TypeError: fields.urlOfFolder.split is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fields.urlOfFolder` is an array with one entry, you need to pull the string out first:

```
var customerid = fields.urlOfFolder[0].split('/')[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

`fields.urlOfFolder` is an `array`. To access the first value from array, use `fields.urlOfFolder[0]`

```js
var fields = {
  urlOfFolder : [ '122/122/47/49/50' ]
};

var customerid = fields.urlOfFolder[0].split('/')[0];
console.log(customerid);
```